# How do I change what my house is registered as?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

Recently, I've moved into a new, larger house. The previous owner had rented out  two thirds of the house, so there are redundant functions. Of course, because of this, we wanted to do the same. However, the local town government told(MA, USA) told us that since it's registered as a single family, we cannot rent it out. **How can we change what the house is registered as?**

Comment: Was the MLS listing for a single family or a 3plex?

Comment: It was listed as a single family. We want to change it to a 3plex.

Comment: Which part of the local town government?

Comment: Did you get a home inspection when you bought the property?

Answer (score 5):

I’d start with the Zoning Board. If your area is zoned single family, the former owners were operating against current ordinances.

If multifamily homes are permitted, I’d go to the building department for guidance on how to get the building approved. If I am wrong, they’ll send you to the right department. I suggest them as they are responsible for having inspected the work done to create the 3 family house in the first place.

Comment: Yes, you need to get the *zoning* changed. But, be aware that your neighbors will be notified of the proposed zoning change and if they complain, you may be denied. If it was previously multi-family for many years, and nobody complained, you will have a good case.

Comment: You think this house had any building inspections for the work? I suppose it's possible, but I'd say pretty unlikely.

Comment: No, but that’s the place to get the inspection done. If he wants to be legal, this is the way.

Comment: But.. the building inspectors really don't want us to have a multi-family. I'm pretty sure it's because the previous owner was terrible.